# What is the sql connection string I need to use to access localhost\SQLEXPRESS with Windows Authentication or SQL Authentication?

Tags: sql-server

've installed SQL Express on my PC hoping to do some practice creating tables and then modifying them. I coded a webpage in Visual Studio to, basically, SELECT * from a table in the SQLEXPRESS, but I can never get the connection string to work. Please help

My connection string

> "Data
>   Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial
>   Catalog=test;User
>   Id=xaa9-PC\xaa9;Password=abcd;"

Error Message:

> Query is select * from tblCustomers
>   where username='johndoe' error is
>   Login failed for user 'x309-PC\x309'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception:
>   Query is select * from tblCustomers
>   where username='johndoe' error is
>   Login failed for user 'x309-PC\x309'.

Comment: Check out [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) - it shows all possible combinations and variations of SQL Server connection strings known to mankind...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try using Windows authentication:

```
Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Answer (score 7):

Try like this:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;User Id=x309;Password=abcd;";
```

Also make sure you have [enabled SQL authentication](http://kbase.gfi.com/showarticle.asp?id=KBID002804).

Comment: That's a Windows DOMAIN\USERNAME so SQL authentication is not the way to go, you need integrated authentication.

Comment: @Ben, with Windows Authentication you don't specify a username and password in the connection string.

Comment: Escaping is not required in connection strings.  I assume the string isn't in C# since the compiler would give an `Unrecognized escape sequence` error for \S

Comment: @Andomar, I think there is a problem with `\x` in the connection string because it is considered as HEX.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Looks like backslash is not an allowed character in SQL Server logins.  So he's probably trying to log in using Windows authentication, and his PC is called `xaa9-PC`

Comment: @Andomar, then why in the error message it is mentioned `x309-PC`?

Comment: @Darin, That's right. What I meant to say was because this is a windows username, that means you cannot use SQL authentication, you have to use Integrated authentication.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: If you try to login using username `a\b` you'll get `Login failed for user 'a\b'.`.  And there can be no such user. SQL Server does not allow you to create a login called `a\b`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing your data connection string in a web.config file you specify your connection like below:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="NorthwindConnString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

but if you are hard coding within a c# based website you have to escape the '\' back slashes:

```
"Data Source=.\\\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True"
```

Even Scott Hanselman can forget [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FixingInstanceFailureWhenConnectingToSQLServer2005Express.aspx)...

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHANU-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Anusha;Integrated Security=True");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_state",con);

        SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "sname";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "sid";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

        con.Close();
        }
```