# Cannot Connect to SQL DataBase

Tags: c#, authentication

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft Access database but i can't get the connection to work using c# to connect but can't get it to work trying to making a login form using sql connection, this is also a local connection

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source ='(local)';Initial Catalog ='UserAccounts.accdb';Integrated Security=true");
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Working");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error with the databse connection");
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        if (rdr != null)
        {
            rdr.Close();
        }
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do `catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.Message); }` what helpful information does that provide?

Comment: @NathanLoding i get a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server. the server was not found or not accessible.Verify that the instance name is correct and that sql server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider : named pipes provider, error : 40 could not opne a connection to sql server)

thats what it says i know i has to do with the way im calling it just not sure what ime doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may sound so simple, but you said you want to connect to **MS Access**, but are using `SqlConnection`, which is specifically to SQL Server, so of course it will never work.

For MS Access you can use `OleDbConnection` with a proper connection string, something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=UserAccounts.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
    using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Working");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error with the database connection\n\n + e.ToString()");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Check the most appropriate connection string [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Data Source` parameter is wrong, I think.  Typically it's like `Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS` if your SQL instance is named "SQLEXPRESS" on your local machine.  Check out these links:

[What is the sql connection string I need to use to access localhost\SQLEXPRESS with Windows Authentication or SQL Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283727/what-is-the-sql-connection-string-i-need-to-use-to-access-localhost-sqlexpress-w)

http://www.connectionstrings.com/