# Sql connection-string for localhost server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-express

I am newbie in this .NET and please don't mind in answering my simple question.
I am trying to write a windows application, where in I am using a localhost SQLserver for database.

I need to know what is the exact connection string for my localhost, if my server name looks like as below:

> > Data Source=HARIHARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True

should i need to give this same as connection string, or is something wrong in this syntax.

whn i try to open my connection.
I am seeing error in opening connection.

How the format of connection string should be? any one please guide me.

I tried like this :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "Data Source=HARIHARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True" ; 
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader r;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from Table1";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();

        r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        con.Close();


    }
```

This code errors out at con.Open();

Comment: Which type of "authentication mode" you are using ?? Is it "Windows Authentication mode" or "SQL Server mode (Mixed mode)" ?? You should use **user id** and **password** in your connection string.

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing?

Answer (score 114):

Using the default instance (i.e., MSSQLSERVER, use the DOT (.))

```
<add name="CONNECTION_STRING_NAME" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Integrated Security=True;" />
```

Answer (score 22):

Choose a database name in Initial Catalog

```
Data Source=HARIHARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=your database name;Integrated Security=True" ;
```

[see more](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/)

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283727/what-is-the-sql-connection-string-i-need-to-use-to-access-localhost-sqlexpress-w) post worked for me to connect to **local** using `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`

Answer (score 19):

You can also use Dot(.) for local key i.e;

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True
```

If you have the default server instance i.e. **MSSQLSERVER**, then just use dot for **Data Source**.

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True
```

Answer (score 10):

Do You have Internal Connection or External Connection. If you did Internal Connection then try this:

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="Your PAth .mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<add name="connstr" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DBName;User Id=username;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The above also works. It ignores the username and password passed in in the connection string. I switched from an environment db to a local one, and it works fine even though my user in the connection string does not exist in this context.

Answer (score 9):

Try this connection string.

```
Data Source=HARIHARAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=yourDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True
```

See this link for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

In .Net configuration I would use something like:

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=..."
```

This information is from https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2016/

Comment: Also see difference between SQL Express and SQL Server Developer Edition: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61659580/1548275

Answer (score 5):

use this connection string :

```
Server=HARIHARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Intial Catalog=persons;Integrated Security=True;
```

rename person with your database name

Comment: we can use Database= persons as well .I do use it

Answer (score 4):

```
string str = @"Data Source=HARIHARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True" ;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public string strConnectionstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\DataBaseName.mdf";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string str = "Data Source=HARIHARAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True" ;
```

Answer (score 2):

When using SQL Express, you need to specify \SQLExpress instance in your connection string:

```
string str = "Data Source=HARIHARAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Data Source=HARIHARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Your_DataBase_name; Integrated Security=true/false; User ID=your_Username;Password=your_Password;
```

[To know more about connection string Click here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/)