# Membership in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

hello to all i can access to asp configuration in VS 2013 with this command

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:8089 /clr:4.0 /ntlm
```

but when i want create user , and click in security tab i get this error

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused
>   by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient
>   permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not
>   being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where
>   you can choose a new data store.
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to
>   connect to SQL Server database.

i run aspnet_regsql and my webconfig code is

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add connectionString="data source=.;Initial Catalog=workDB;Integrated Security=True;" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="AspNetSqlProvider" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

please help me

Comment: What kind of SQL database do you have installed locally?  If it's SQL Express, see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796298/sql-connection-string-for-localhost-server

Comment: @TabAlleman i use sql server standard edition

Comment: Try "data source=localhost;..." instead of the dot in your connection string.

Comment: i do it , but i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Everything is in the error message. Server defined by your connection string is unavailable. This can be caused by multiple reasons:

- Wrong connection string.
- Inactive Sql Server service .
- Disabled TCP/IP access in your server settings.

If you are using MS SQL Server, try to complete next steps.

Firstly, open [Sql Server Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx) and check that service is running, if not, start it manually. Secondly, check the name of your server instance, maybe you should change connection string. Thirdly, go to network configuration tab, and verify that TCP/IP is enabled.

After that,you can try to connect to server with your favourite tool. With SQLCMD you can type `sqlcmd -S .` in command line.

Comment: i check your steps , all thing is ok

Comment: Ok, if you can connect to your server instance, problem is somewhere else. Check, that connectionString name specified in your `membership` and `rolemanager` configuration sections is `LocalSqlServer`. You can read more info about membership configuration [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.100).aspx).