# Cannot connect to SQL Server in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, database-connection

I installed SQL Server and Visual Studio and tried to do my university project.

I can connect to SQL Server in Management Studio but can not connect in Visual Studio!

- Remote connecting is enabled
- all services are running
- and everything is ok but I dont know why I get this error :

> A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.verify that the instance name is correct and the ...

What's wrong with this code?

```
 SqlConnection sqcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Badan_Sazi;Integrated Security=True");

 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
 com.Connection = sqcon;
 com.CommandText = "SELECT tbl_morabi.family   as 'lname'  FROM tbl_morabi";

 com.Connection.Open();
```

I also tried `.`, `localhost`, `my pc name` ... same error anyway

- Visual Sudio 2012
- SQL Server Express 2012

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL Server **Express** defaults to a `SQLEXPRESS` instance name

So try to use `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` as your server+instance name.

And if that doesn't work: what **server name** do you use in **Management Studio** to connect to your SQL Server instance?? Use that name!

Comment: thank you . tried that and now syntax error "Error 2 Unrecognized escape sequence
"

Comment: @hrh_fourtyseven: You need \\ to put a \ in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your connectionString. It should be like that below.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SampleConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=machinename\instancename;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=60;Connect Timeout=30″ providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: thank you. visual studio does not accept mymachine\instancename because of syntax error ! should I type it different?

Comment: If you use default settings, you should write `.\SQLEXPRESS`, for other things you should check SQL SERVER Server Name

Comment: Use `Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB` instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52838019/1548275