# Sql difference between localhost and (LocalDb)/MSSQLLocalDB

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, localdb

I noticed I used a connection string to migrate an Identity Database.  No matter what I did I looked and looked but I couldn't find the database.  So I re-evaluated my connection strings and noticed they're not that similar:

```
var connectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
var connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;database=gritzy.IdentityServer4.dbo;trusted_connection=yes;";
```

One just specified the server as localhost, and the other doesn't even specify a server at all.

I was under the impression that localhost would just use the default MSSQLSERVER Instance name.

What is the difference between the Data Source, and server?

Comment: You will have better luck if you include the `Provider=` into your connection string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Data Source" and "Server" are synonyms, so no difference.

localhost specifies the default SQL Server instance on your machine.

`(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` is the default LocalDB instance on your machine

Comment: what do you mean by sql server instance please? we can have many instance with different name like localhost , localhost1, localhost2 for the same sql server?

Comment: No the instances name consists of hostname\instancename - like localhost\MSSQLSERVER or localhost\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Thanks .. I needed (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB too ....  What is the one that connects to when I just type myMachineName in there ?

Answer (score 8):

If you install both SQLExpress(SqlLocalDB) and SqlServer you are in for a big confusion.

You may have seen connection string like this:

### SqlServer:

```
var connectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

### SqlExpress:

```
var connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;database=gritzy.IdentityServer4.dbo;trusted_connection=yes;";
```

The first is the connection string you use to connect to the SQLServer, which asked you to specify the root folder when you installed SqlServer. The default is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SqlServer`  but you can put it in wherever you want. For example, if I specify the root to be `C:\Source\DB` then it is `C:\source\DB\MSSQL15.MSSQLLOCALDB\MSSQL\DATA`. The point here is a SQLServer instance is machine-scoped. One instance per server/machine.

The second is the connection string for SQLExpress, and the DB files are usually stored in the AppData folder for each user, such as `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB`. Note that each user logged in to the same machine can have his own data file because each user has his own appData folder.

If you have both SQLExpress/SqlLocalDB and SqlServer installed, bring up SSMS (management studio) you can connect to both at the same time and you will notice they have different databases.