# Not able to insert and view the data in C# using ADO.net

Tags: c#, class, ado.net

I am new to C# . I am trying to create an simple application using ADO.Net in which I just want to insert and view the employee details. I am not able to insert and view the details of the employees. The method which I want to call is add_employee() which exist in EmployeeDAL class.

```
namespace Employee
{
    class EmployeeDAL
    { 
        public void add_employee(EmployeeBO emp)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=abc";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "sp_insert";
            command.Connection = con;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empname", emp.EmployeeName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deptid", emp.DepatNumber);
            con.Open();
            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result > 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Record inserted successfully");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Some Error Occured");
            con.Close();
           //return result;
        }
    }
}
```

My main method is like this

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;



namespace Employee
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employee Management system");
            Console.WriteLine("Menu\n");
            Console.WriteLine("1.Add Employees\n");
            Console.WriteLine("2.View Employees\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your choice\n");
            int ch = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            EmployeeBO emp = new EmployeeBO();
            EmployeeDAL dal = new EmployeeDAL();

            switch(ch)
            {
                case 1:

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the employee");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
                    emp.EmployeeName = name;
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the department of the employee");
                    int deptNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    emp.DepatNumber = deptNo;

                     dal.add_employee(emp);
                    break;
```

I am not able to insert and view the already present data.

My EmployeeBO class consists of only the Employee class .

My sp_insert stored procedure is

```
create proc sp_insert(
@empname varchar(20),
@deptid int
)
as begin
insert into employee(empName,deptno) values(@empname,@deptid)
end
```

This is how I created my  tables

```
create table employee( empno int identity(1000,1) primary key , empName varchar(20)) 
alter table employee add deptno int 

create table department(deptno int identity(1,1) primary key, deptName varchar(20))


alter table employee add constraint fk1 foreign key(deptno) references department(deptno)
```

Comment: class EmployeeDAL should be public. What is the error message?

Comment: Did you try to debug this code? Are you sure that the variable _ch_ holds the value 1 when you enter the last code above? Did you see the input requests for name and deptNo?

Comment: My employee name is "uma" and department id is 2. My department table contains entries for 1,2 and 3 department id. So foreign key violation is not possible

Comment: con.Open(); is the last line hit by the debugger

Comment: `string connectionString = "Data Source=SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=abc";` looks like it may be incomplete. https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ When you run the code, an exception will be thrown on `con.Open`. What does the exception say?

Comment: I am not getting any exception....when i run the app in console, I simple enter 1 for the option 1 , enter uma for employee name and 2 for department id ..that's it...nothing happens after this

Comment: You tried `localhost` like shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283762/34092 ?

Comment: That might look something like `Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=abc;Trusted_Connection=True;` or `Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=abc;Trusted_Connection=True;`

Answer (score -1):

As @mjwills, I think this is a case of running the code that has not been compiled.

This could happen, for example, if you Run the code (F5) but there are compilation errors and you choose to run the last version that compiled. (And there are other circumstances that could lead to running not the code that's shown in the editor).

One solution is to add a change that allows you to confirm that you're running fresh code, recompile and run again.

You could also put something in the code that does NOT compile and confirm that the Run/Debug failed.